# Use navigation drawer menu in child Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I use sliding drawer menu in my android project and 
I use one drawer menu for all of myActivies

I want in root Activity when click on actionbar`s icon the drawer menu is open!

 and in childs Activities when click on actionbar's icon go to parent Activity

like google play or gmail and ...

how I can do this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the navigation as usual (with drawertoggle and everything), then call

```
_toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

It will hide the drawer icon (the three vertical lines) and display the up caret. The up icon click event will not be handle by the drawer and will finish the activity (if you do so in the `OnOptionsItemSelected`).

Answer (score 0):

yup, you can use Navigation drawer in the layout and as well as in the java code.

check this url for screenshot

https://developer.android.com/design/media/navigation_drawer_holo_dark_light.png

Comment: This should rather be a comment to the OP, since it doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: yes,  I know i can ,and I do this! but my qyestion is how i can inplement actionbar in different activity?